# FullCalendar header buttons vertically

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar, dropdown

I'm using fullcalendar and I want to change the right header buttons orientation to vertical instead of horizontal.

I changed a few things, so I've got the "change view buttons" hidden, when I click on the "menu" button all header buttons are showed, but with horizontal orientations.

How can I make it look like a dropdown?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Almost solved the problem.
The dropdown is vertical but is pushing the rest of the content down

[image]

the code for the div with the buttons is:

```
.fc-button-group {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
align-content: center;
width: 70px; 
position:relative;
}
```

I already changed the z-index but can't make it work.